# Rectification of a lot of images using ERDAS IMAGINE

Tags: batch, erdas-imagine

I want to rectify many images of same area but different dates at a time in ERDAS Imagine
1 I did this using Batch processing but I have no out put. Second I did reproject many images using Batch process. It ran but the projection did not change. What is the error?

If it could not be happen in ERDAS IMAGINE then what is the purpose of this Batch in ERDAS Imagine Rectification process